# Mostrar botones y contenido en modal si existe contenido en directorios

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap, modal

Estoy trabajando un modal en **bootstrap**, pero necesito que al abrir me cargue un contenido dinámico, que busque o analice si existen ciertos archivos en un directorio y que de encontrarlo se muestren distintos *tabs* en este modal.

Actualmente tengo este *script*, pero no sé bien cómo configurarlo para que cargue contenido según existan o no:

```html
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: "./files/" + nombre_variable + ".pdf",
    success: function () {
      AHExist = true;
    },
    error: function () {
      enableErrorMessage();
    },
  });
</script>
```

Actualmente tengo el modal de esta forma, y creo que dicho script deberia tenerlo dentro de la seccion dondo se carga el documento pdf.

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalf22">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <!-- <h4 class="modal-title">Detalles del Formulario 22</h4> -->
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                        <p class="circModalBtn">
                          <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Insctrucción</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                          <i class="fa fa-flag-o fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>detalles</h4></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                          <i class="fa fa-folder-o fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Resumen documentos</h4></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="example-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#example" role="tab" aria-controls="example" aria-selected="false">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Ejemplos</h4></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <script>
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'HEAD',
                            url: './files/{l73}/l73_instruccion.pdf./files/' + l73_4b + '.pdf',
                            success: function() {
                            AHExist = true;
                            },
                            error: function() {
                            enableErrorMessage();
                            }
                            });

                    </script>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                    <embed src="./files/l73_4b/l73_instruccion.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" style="margin-top: -420px;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                    <embed src="./files/l73_4b/l73_instruccion.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" style="margin-top: -420px;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="example" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="example-tab">
                    <embed src="./files/l73_4b/otronombre.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" style="margin-top: -420px;" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Si hay algún ejemplo de algo así también me sería útil para poder resolver dicho problema.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias utilizar Jquery ya que estas utilizando bootstrap. Entonces con Jquery  validar que el modal se abrio  y entonces ejecutar tu ajax y hacer los cambios dentro del modal. Por ejemplo:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
       $.ajax({
            url: "./files/" + nombre_variable + ".pdf",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data)
           {
            if(data.status !== undefined) 
            //En este if puedes hacer validacion por true tambien.
            {
              //Aca harias los cambos dentro del modal.
            }
        }
       });
      })
      </script>
```

Comment: Gracias, el modal ya lo muestro, me falta esta sección que es para cargar los contenidos de forma dinamica, según existan o no en un directorio de la aplicación...

Comment: Lo que tendrias que hacer, es Agregar el Ajax dentro del ejemplo. Porque si no, vas a tener problemas al momento de usar Ajax y luego querer hacer el update en el modal. Por el tema de que son asincronos.  Te actualice la respuesta agregando el Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente tengo este codigo con el cual me esta funcionando la busqueda y carga de dichos archivos, pero no entiendo si debo aplicar un nuevo script por cada tabs o deberia hacerlo aparte?

```
<div id="tmpModal">
  <!--   Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalf22">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                    <div class="modalbutton">
                      <div>
                      <p class="circModalBtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </p>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <h4>Insctrucción</h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
                    <div class="modalbutton">
                      <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-flag-o fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <h4>Detalles</h4></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function() {
                          $('.btnModal').click(function() {
                              $('#home').html('<embed src="./files/'+this.id+'/'+this.id+'_ejemplo.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" />')
                              if(exist != undefined){
                                  console.log("Se ha clickeado el id " +this.id);
                              }
                          });
                      });
                  </script>
                  <embed id="emb">
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function() {
                          $('.btnModal').click(function() {
                              $('#profile').html('<embed src="./files/'+this.id+'/'+this.id+'_glosario.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" style="margin-top: -420px;" />')
                          });
                      });
                  </script>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```